# regex match only specific file lines

Tags: regex

I have a file containing lines like:

```
13  
13-55  
some text 11
```

I want to create a regex to match only first to type of lines, but not the last one.
Reges created by me is `[0-9\-]+`

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify that you are testing from the beggining to the end of the string:

Try with following regex:

```
^[0-9-]+$
```

Comment: @user2655799 If you find my answer helpful, remember to mark it with the thick on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Try using anchors (`^` and `$` to denote beginning and end of string respectively) and use the multiline option (this one depends on the language/engine/environment of the regex).

```
^[0-9-]+$
```

Note, you can drop the backslash for the `-` if it's at the beginning or end of a character class.

Comment: @user2655799 You're welcome! If you have an more related questions you can ask :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match lines which start with number.

```
^[0-9-]+$
```